# Поиск хэштегов в строке

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Друзья, я не специалист в выражениях, поэтому прошу помощи. Составил следующее выражение для поиска хэштегов из строки `#\w+`

Возможно, ошибка в php.

Собственно, весь код:

```
$name = 'a:1:{i:0;a:2:{i:0;s:4:"#hey";i:1;s:9:"#hasgtags";}}';

preg_match_all("#\w+", $name, $hashtag);  
echo ' <li><a href="#">#'.$hashtag[0][1].'</a>';
```

Answer (score 1):

Вероятно, вам нужно что-то подобное

```
$str = 'a:1:{i:0;a:2:{i:0;s:4:"#hey";i:1;s:9:"#hasgtags";}}';

preg_match_all('~#\w+~', $str, $arr);
echo '<pre>'; var_dump($arr); echo '</pre>';
```